# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object. Null pointer

Tags: apex, trigger

I am checking in the Cases list in my trigger, for record type Id and only if case is of that particular Record Type do I want a SOQL query to run.

But since a list is empty it throws a Null Pointer error. How can I prevent this?

```
if(cases[0].RecordTypeId == 'RecordTypeId') {

    cases_Creative = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber,Counter_Survey__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId ='RecordTypeId' and Counter_Survey__c != null and createdDate = Last_N_Days:10 order by Counter_Survey__c desc limit 1];
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may need to bulkify your code, because multiple records could occur in a trigger. That said, to solve your immediate problem, you just need to use the && shortcircuit operator:

```
if(!cases.isEmpty() && cases[0].RecordTypeId == 'RecordTypeId') {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply SFDCFOX. But getting the same null Pointer error.

Comment: Did you define `cases`? Try adding `System.debug(cases == null);` before the `if` statement and see if it ends up being `null` in the debug logs.

Comment: @battery.cord: Debug says 'false' when I put system.debug before if statement with cases == null. thanks!

Comment: Hey @battery.cord any pointers here please.

Comment: @Abhishek Are you sure you're on the right line number, then? Maybe it's actually a completely different line? Assuming cases == null was false, then neither line is the problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox Please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170194/system-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-de-reference-a-null-object-class-caseau

Added the full code and line number where error is being thrown at.