# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.CaseAutoNumberHandler.updateCounterSurvey: line 27, column 1

Tags: apex, trigger

```
public class CaseAutoNumberHandler {

    public static void updateCounterSurvey(List<Case> cases)
    {   
        Integer maxLead_Creative;
        Integer maxLead_MCS;
        Integer maxLead_SSR;
        List<case> cases_Creative;
        List<case> cases_MCS;
        List<case> cases_SSR;


        system.debug(Cases == null);
      if(!cases.isEmpty() && cases[0].RecordTypeId == '012200000002NeU') {
            system.debug('X - In IF for Creative:'+ cases[0].RecordTypeId);
        cases_Creative = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber,Counter_Survey__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId ='012200000002NeU' and Counter_Survey__c != null and createdDate = Last_N_Days:10 order by Counter_Survey__c desc limit 1];
       }
       if(!cases.isEmpty() && cases[0].RecordTypeId =='012200000002OtP'){
            system.debug('X - In IF for MCS:'+cases[0].RecordTypeId);
        cases_MCS = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, MCS_AutoNumber__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId ='012200000002OtP' and MCS_AutoNumber__c != null and createdDate = Last_N_Days:10 order by MCS_AutoNumber__c desc limit 1];
        }
        if(!cases.isEmpty() && cases[0].RecordTypeId =='012200000002Ny1'){
            system.debug('X - In IF for SSR:'+cases[0].RecordTypeId);
        cases_SSR = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, SSR_AutoNumber__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId ='012200000002Ny1' and SSR_AutoNumber__c != null and createdDate = Last_N_Days:10 order by SSR_AutoNumber__c desc limit 1];       
        }
         if(cases_Creative[0].Counter_Survey__c ==0){

            maxLead_Creative = 0;
        }
        else{

            maxLead_Creative = Integer.valueOf(cases_Creative[0].Counter_Survey__c);
        }
        if(cases_MCS[0].MCS_AutoNumber__c==0){

            maxLead_MCS = 0;
        }else{

            maxLead_MCS = Integer.valueOf(cases_MCS[0].MCS_AutoNumber__c);     
        }
        if(cases_SSR[0].SSR_AutoNumber__c==0){
            maxLead_SSR = 1;
        }else{

            maxLead_SSR = Integer.valueOf(cases_SSR[0].SSR_AutoNumber__c);         
        } 
        for(Case caseList:cases)
        {
            if(caseList.RecordTypeId =='012200000002NeU' && caseList.Region__c == 'UK & IReland'){
                maxLead_Creative++;
                caseList.Counter_Survey__c = maxLead_Creative;
            }
            else if(caseList.RecordTypeId =='012200000002OtP' && caseList.Region__c == 'UK & IReland'){
                maxLead_MCS++;
                caseList.MCS_AutoNumber__c = maxLead_MCS;
            }else 
            if(caseList.RecordTypeId =='012200000002Ny1' && caseList.Region__c == 'UK & IReland')
            {
                maxlead_SSR++;
                caseList.SSR_AutoNumber__c = maxlead_SSR ;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Class.CaseAutoNumberHandler.updateCounterSurvey: line 27, column 1

Comment: Whn I try creating Case of Record Type Creative error at line 36
And when I try creating Case of Record Type Self Service Request and New Campaign error at line 27. Any help will be greatly apprecriated. Thanks!

Comment: There is always a possibility that your query will return no data. You are attempting to access a position of your list directly which is causing you an error due to the list being null. You should always query the RecordType object to get specific ids instead of hard coding into Apex. These ids will change after code migration.

Comment: @TSmith Thanks for the reply.  I am very new to coding. Could you please be more specific how I could improve my code and get rid of these errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several problems, mostly related to hard-coded ID values and a lack of proper bulkification, but to answer your immediate question, your code first populates one of three lists, and then later assumes that all of the lists were populated (but at least two of them will be null).

You'll want to initialize your lists first:

```
    List<case> cases_Creative = new Case[0];
    List<case> cases_MCS = new Case[0];
    List<case> cases_SSR = new Case[0];
```

And then check if they're empty before you use them:

```
    if(cases_Creative.size() > 0 && cases_Creative[0].Counter_Survey__c ==0){
```

Comment: I get this error after making changes as suggested,

Apex trigger CaseAutoNumber caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CaseAutoNumber: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject: Class.CaseAutoNumberHandler.updateCounterSurvey: line 26, column 1

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting an [NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) (null pointer exception) as your query on line 16. I am not 100% sure as to why this is returning no data but have a strong feeling its due to hard coding the record type id into your where clause.

```
cases_Creative = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber,Counter_Survey__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId ='012200000002NeU' and .....
```

I would approach this by passing in a [bind variable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm) holding the record type id queried directly from the environment at runtime.

```
Id recordTypeId = [
    select id
    from RecordType
    where sObjectType = 'Case'
    and DeveloperName ='<Record Type Name>'].id;
```

Your query would then become something like:

```
Id recordTypeId = [
            select id
            from RecordType
            where sObjectType = 'Case'
            and DeveloperName ='<Record Type Name>'].id;
        cases_Creative = [SELECT Id, CaseNumber,Counter_Survey__c FROM Case Where RecordTypeId = :recordTypeId and Counter_Survey__c != null and createdDate = Last_N_Days:10 order by Counter_Survey__c desc limit 1];
```

Further on in your code I would also guard against the List being null.

```
if(cases_Creative != null && cases_Creative[0].Counter_Survey__c ==0){
    maxLead_Creative = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks again, made changes as suggested. I get this now

"CaseAutoNumber: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject Class.CaseAutoNumberHandler.updateCounterSurvey: line 21, column 1"

Same Error at respective Lines of code when trying to create a case of that recordtype.

Comment: There's no need to waste a query to get the record type Id; they can either use `Case.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('<record type name>')` or just use the record type in the query directly: `WHERE RecordType.Name = '<record type name>'.

Comment: @sfdcfox But that is throwing Null Pointer Error. :(

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't Hard-code the Record Type Id in the query. Use either custom label/ query based on developer name or Schema.SObjectType."Object Name".getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('RecordTypeName').getRecordTypeId()
2. Since your query might not always return a value therefore you are getting the null pointer exception. Handle this using try catch or make sure that it always return some records by updating the where conditions.

Comment: A query never returns a null value instead of a list.

Comment: @Adrian Larson: I have done as suggested by TSmith. Please help